# I want difference between consecutive date rows in a column sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have data like this:

```
  date
2019-12-10
2019-12-21
2019-12-30
```

I want something like this:

```
  date            Time_difference
2019-12-10            11
2019-12-21             9
2019-12-30
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lead()`:

```
select date, datediff(lead(date) over (order by date), date)
from t;
```

This is available in MySQL 8+.  One method in earlier versions of MySQL is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select date,
       datediff( (select min(date)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.date > t.date
                 ),
                 date
               ) as diff
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, just use `lead()`:

```
select
    date,
    datediff(lead(date) over(order by date), date) days_diff
from mytable
```

In earlier versions, an option is a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    t.date,
    datediff(
        (select min(t1.date) from mytable t1 where t1.date > t.date),
        t.date
    ) days_diff
from mytable t
```